# Can't connect to Azure File Storage using “net use” command - System error 5

Tags: azure

I'm trying to mount a Azure file storage to my local computer on Windows 7 using the net use command generated in the (new) Azure portal:

net use Z: \foo.file.core.windows.net\testshare /u:foo [PASSWORD]

But I keep getting: "System error 5 has occurred. Access is Denied"

Comment: Is the single \ before foo.file.core.windows.net a typo, it should be \\foo.file.core.windows.net\etc... also, are you using a storage account or an office 365 account?

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation you need windows 8 or server 2012 because you need a client that supports smb3 [Azure docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/#what-is-azure-file-storage)

> 2. Are Azure File shares visible publicly over the Internet, or are they only reachable from Azure?
>
> As long as port 445 (TCP Outbound) is open and your client supports the SMB 3.0 protocol (e.g., Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012), your file share is available via the Internet.

Comment: Actually, I thought the documentation specifically notes that Windows 7 is compatible via SMB 2.1 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/ - is that incorrect?

Comment: @IceMage the document is entirely correct, but you are either not reading it fully or don't understand the different scenarios. 2.1 is supported when using powershell and from within the same region. It isn't supported from on premises access for mounting the drive the way suggested want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mount an Azure file share from an external Windows 7 computer, because Windows 7 does not support SMB 3.0 file sharing protocol.

This newly posted grid from microsoft might help others.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows